# How to write a measure in power bi to count items based on their status as of selected date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I cannot think of a solution for this:
I have a table with the following columns:
`Employee id, hired date, fired date, current_status`.

`current_status` is a conditional column showing status of employee for a current date i.e. if fired date is blank the status is "working", else the status is "fired".

I want to create a measure, which would show count of employees by their status as of end of selected month.

E.g an employee's current status may be "fired", but as of end of June 2019 his status was "working", so in the context of previous date he should be counted as working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator function, such as  `FILTER` or `SUMX`, to decide the status of each employee based on the dates.

Here is an example to count the number of working employees at the ending date of the currently displayed period.

```
Working Employees Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Employee,
        Employee[Hired Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) &&
        (
            ISBLANK ( Employee[Fired Date] ) ||
            Employee[Fired Date] > MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided above by Kosuke Sakai is incorrect. This measure would not produce any rows for dates where employee status did not change.

For example if we have this kind of Data with just a single employee:

- Jan 10 : Active
- Jan 12 : Suspended
- Jan 14 : Terminated

it would produce 0 for Active employees count for Jan 11, while the correct result would be 1, since the only employee we have is "Active" since Jan 10.